# Future Method is not updating value of a field

Tags: triggers, salesforce, visualforce, force.com

I want to implement synchronization in salesforce using apex.

My Requirement is that, i have to update a field from the future method.

I have a field in database with name Counter_*c and i am calling a method that method will call 3 future method. Those future method will try to increment value of counter*_c by 1. But field is not getting update.

Here is my code:

public void generateReports() {

```
  ReportHistory__c repHst = new ReportHistory__c();
  repHst.Counter__c = 0;
  insert repHst;

  generateReport1(repHst.Id);
  generateReport2(repHst.Id);
  generateReport3(repHst.Id);
```

}

```
@future
public static void generateReport1(Id id) {

List<ReportHistory__c> lstRep = [select Counter__c rom ReportHistory__c where Id = :id];
     if(!lstRep.isEmpty()) {
        ++lstRep[0].Counter__c;
     }
     update lstRep;
}


@future
public static void generateReport2(Id id) {

List<ReportHistory__c> lstRep = [select Counter__c rom ReportHistory__c where Id = :id];
     if(!lstRep.isEmpty()) {
        ++lstRep[0].Counter__c;
     }
     update lstRep;
}


@future
public static void generateReport3(Id id) {

List<ReportHistory__c> lstRep = [select Counter__c rom ReportHistory__c where Id = :id];
     if(!lstRep.isEmpty()) {
        ++lstRep[0].Counter__c;
     }
     update lstRep;
}
```

After executing above code i want Counter__c should be 3. But its still 0 or sometime its 1.

Please help me, if there is any way so that i can control future call so that every future call should update value of Counter__c by 1.

Thanks,
Vivek

Answer (score 1):

From your example code it appears the `lstRep.isEmpty()` check is missing the negation.

E.g. Add a `!` in the if condition.

```
@future
public static void generateReport1(Id id) {

    List<ReportHistory__c> lstRep = [select Counter__c rom ReportHistory__c where Id = :id];
    if(!lstRep.isEmpty()) {
        lstRep[0].Counter__c++;
    }
    update lstRep;
}
```

It is also possible that your future methods are being pulled off the Queue and processed by different Application Servers in parallel. If this is the case your have a concurrency issue. Have a read of [Asynchronous Processing in Force.com](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/async_processing/salesforce_async_processing.pdf). You could try adding the `FOR UPDATE` keyword to your SOQL query, but this may cause some of your future methods to timeout.